# Making a decision tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have ten systems, A, B, C, ..., J.
Each system can be up or down.
If, for example, systems A, B, D and J are down, with the remainder being up then I want to take action X.
If systems C, D, and H are down, with the remainder being up then I want to take action Y.
If systems A, E, F, H and I are down, with the remainder being up then I want to take action Z.

I am wanting to write a program that will print the various combinations (I believe with 10 systems and each can be up or down there are 100 combinations).

I have this so far:

```
import itertools
status_list = (
    "Up",
    "Down",
)
component_list = (
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E",
    "F",
    "G",
    "G",
    "I",
    "J",
)
combinations = itertools.product(component_list, status_list)
```

Comment: Well, there are 2^10 combinations = 1024

Comment: There are actually `2^10` possible states. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/String.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out every possible combination of `Up` and `Down` using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
components = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
statuses = ['Up', 'Down']

for state in itertools.product(statuses, repeat=len(components)):
    for c,s in zip(components, state):
        print '{}:{}'.format(c,s),
    print
```

This produces output like the following:

```
A:Up B:Up C:Up D:Up E:Up F:Up G:Up H:Up I:Up J:Up
A:Up B:Up C:Up D:Up E:Up F:Up G:Up H:Up I:Up J:Down
...
A:Up B:Down C:Down D:Down E:Down F:Down G:Down H:Down I:Down J:Up
A:Up B:Down C:Down D:Down E:Down F:Down G:Down H:Down I:Down J:Down
A:Down B:Up C:Up D:Up E:Up F:Up G:Up H:Up I:Up J:Up
A:Down B:Up C:Up D:Up E:Up F:Up G:Up H:Up I:Up J:Down
...
A:Down B:Down C:Down D:Down E:Down F:Down G:Down H:Down I:Down J:Up
A:Down B:Down C:Down D:Down E:Down F:Down G:Down H:Down I:Down J:Down
```

It deals nicely with a variable number of components or states (for example, you could make `states = ['Up', 'Down', 'Unknown']` and you would get 3^10 = 59049 outputs).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a binary representation, we could use `0` to represent `Up` and `1` to represent `Down`

Our values would range from `0`, to `10^2-1`,

which is `0` to `1023`, or

`0000000000` to `1111111111`.

So we could just loop from 0 to 1023, printing the numbers out in a 10-digit binary format:

```
for x in range(2**10):
    print '{0:010b}'.format(x)
```

Outputs:

```
0000000000
0000000001
0000000010
0000000011
0000000100
0000000101
0000000110
...etc
```

---

If you wanted to get fancier and print `up` and `down` instead of`0` and `1`, you could examine the digits one-by-one and convert:

```
for x in range(2**10):

    #Iterate over each character c in the binary number x
    #Convert c to an int
    #Look up the value in status_list by taking c mod length of status list
    print(" ".join(status_list[int(c)%len(status_list)] for c in '{0:010b}'.format(x)))
```

Outputs:

```
Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up
Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Down
Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Down Up
Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Up Down Down
```

Comment: You could get even fancier and add the component_list values in front of their respective columns if you wanted to.